# Passing collection name dynamically

Tags: asp.net, collections, http-headers

Can any one suggest for a simple but tricky query. I have a function  like

```
public object GetPropertyValue(object obj_, string property_)
{
      return HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[property_];
}
```

But I want to use Obj_ instead of hard coding the headers in return value. Because it can be Headers/ cookies/...or anything

Something like HttpContext.Current.Request.obj_[property_];

Please anyone???

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
HTTPContext.Current.Request[YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME] ;
```

it has an indexer which reads from the QueryString, Form, Cookies, or ServerVariables collections.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx